# Inequalities involving real numbers

Tags: inequality

I am a high school student who has just been introduced to inequalities. I have tried to prove this one using comparisons as I find no other inequalities helping here. Any idea how to solve this one?

Let $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$ be real numbers such that $x_{1}^{2}+\cdots+x_{n}^{2}=1 . k \geq 2$ be an integer. Let
$$
S:=\left\{a_{1} x_{1}+\cdots+a_{n} x_{n} \mid 0<a_{i}<k, a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall i=1,2, \ldots, n\right\}
$$
Prove that

(a) if $s, t \in S$ then $|s-t| \leq(k-1) \sqrt{n}$.

(b) there exists $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in \mathbb{Z},\left|a_{i}\right|<k$ for all $i$ and not all $a_{i} \mathrm{~s}$ are 0 , such that
$$
\left|a_{1} x_{1}+\cdots+a_{n} x_{n}\right| \leq \frac{(k-1) \sqrt{n}}{k^{n}-1}
$$

Comment: Hello @tao, can you show your attempts?

Comment: Hint for (a): Write $s-t$ as $(a_1-b_1)x_1+\cdots+(a_n-b_n)x_n$, and keep in mind that you can choose the sign of each $x_i$ to make each $(a_i-b_i)x_i$ non-negative.

Comment: @Barry Cipra, I think no need to choose the signs of each $x_{i}$, because we already have the modulus sign right??

Comment: @RAHUL, you are quite right.

Comment: 1st inequality is simple though, but I am not sure how to solve the second one. If you know it then please give me a hint.